# Problemas con p:ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

tengo un problema con `p:ajax` dentro de un `p:selectOneMenu` al momento de seleccionar un item Sí agrega pero en un item en específico no lo agrega.

Es decir en la imagen puedo agregar ANTIQUING, STONE SETTING6, pero al agregar STONE SETTINGs7 no me agrega sino que salta un error.

El code es este:

```
<p:selectOneMenu   value="#{ac.nombre_actividad}" id="nom" required="true" effect="fold"  filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith"> 
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select..." itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{editFicha.actividades}"
        var="acti" itemLabel="#{acti.nombre_actividad} --> #{acti.factoXmil}"
        itemValue="#{acti.nombre_actividad}">
    </f:selectItems>
     <p:ajax event="change" update=":f1:pv :f1:to1 :f1:pieza2:prp:acti :f1:all :f1:growl"
         listener="#{editFicha.subjectSelectionChanged}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en la captura de AJAX sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Fue un erorr de tipeo por parte de el departamento de planificación algún caracter especial se introdujo cuando copiaba y pegaba.